# about on line 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from datetime import date
name = input("what's your name?")
surname = input("what's your surname?")
birth_year = input("what's your birth year?")
initials = name[0] + surname[0]
current = date.today()
age = current.year - birth_year
print('your initials are ' + initials.upper() + ' and you are ' + str(age) + ' years old')
```

Comment: You'll need to leanr how to post on SO. The title, and the text in the post should explain what the problem is, not : I have a problem ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting int to a string.

An input in python is always a string. Therefore, when you ask the user `birth_year`, the number the user types is evaluated as a string.

Therefore `age = current.year - birth_year` is actually: `int - string`.

To avoid so do:

```
age = current.year - int(birth_year)
```

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: Change yours to: `age = current.year - int(birth_year)`. It is transforming the `birth_year` from string to integer

Answer (score 0):

Please perform below mentioned changes and code will work fine. 
Line number 4 has been changed to accept input year in int format instead of string format (which is default format of input)

```
`from datetime import date
name = input("what's your name?")
surname = input("what's your surname?")
birth_year = int(input("what's your birth year?"))
initials = name[0] + surname[0]
current = date.today()
age = current.year - int(birth_year)
print('your initials are ' + initials.upper() + ' and you are ' + str(age) + ' years 
old')`
```